# Message handlers

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a thread, initialthread that executes a task  every n seconds. This is enclosed in activity A.  i have a message handler on activity B.

```
mHandler = new Handler(){
public void handleMessage(Message msg)
  {
   //perform task
    executetask();
  }
};
```

Will this handler excutetask() whenever the initialthread finishes executing??
thanks

Answer (score 1):

It will execute whenever you pass the massage from the initial thread.

I mean whenever you call `.sentMessage()` from the initial thread.